# Rate of change of area of a circular loop exiting a uniform magnetic field

Tags: calculus, derivatives, circles

The question is to find the variation in induced electromotive force w.r.t to time or put simply $\varepsilon(t)$ for a circular loop being removed from the region of the magnetic field at a constant velocity $v$.
Obviously $$\varepsilon= \frac{d\phi}{dt}$$ Now $$\phi = BA\cos \theta=B(\pi r^2)$$ Now, $$\varepsilon= \frac{d\phi}{dt} = 2\pi rB \frac{dr}{dt}$$
But there's no clear way to determine $\frac{dr}{dt}$. So is there any other way to determine the rate of change of area (how much of the circle is leaving the region per $dt$ time). 
Any help would be very good right now.

Comment: $r$ isn't changing.  What's changing is how much of the loop is in the field.

Answer (score 1):

The radius isn't changing, just the portion of the loop within the field.

The flux is $\Phi=2B\int_{-R+c}^R\sqrt{R^2-x^2} \ dx$

Where c =  beginning position of vertical line where ring meets field boundary.

$dc/dt $ is the rate of leaving the field.

Using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:

$$\frac{d\Phi}{dt}=-2B\frac{dc}{dt}\sqrt{2cR-c^2}$$

Comment: ok so if I had to graph $\frac{d\phi}{dt}$ versus $t$ what would it look like?

Comment: It looks like a semi-circle. You can find this by assuming dc/dt is a constant, equivalent to the center moving at constant speed.  c starts at zero and increases at a constant rate, so c=kt. Plug that in, you find that, so far as graphing is concerned, you can replace the c with a t to get a feel for the shape. The difference otherwise is a matter of scaling.

Comment: All right, thank you I haven't got all of this down yet but certainly some food for thought!